# Android NDK JNI binary code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I just created my first Android application that uses JNI and NDK, the simple Hello-JNI to speak. With a unique function that returns a string.
I signed APK unpacked and if I see the .so files that do not seem compiled natively. I expected a binary code. I read the name of function and string.
My goal is to use the SDK to write native code to hide the strings that are not clouded by proguard.
I used Android Studio 2.1.2

Build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.Gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danielezampieri.jniapp"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 18
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "jniapp"
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

local.properties

```
ndk.dir=P\:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=P\:\\Android\\sdk
```

Comment: Do I get you right, you open .so file and see just plain text, not hex commands? btw, i recommend you to try android studio 2.2 preview 5. It supports different build systems (CMake, Android.mk makefile, ndk-build). Many bugs fixed since 2.1

Comment: I wait for 2.2 production release, I suspect there are many change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your string is defined in C/C++ like:

```
char *mySecretString = "some secret";
```

Then of course it **is** readable in `.so`, while it **is** natively compiled.
Compilation is not obfuscation, but translation of code into machine code of target platform. The string is not code, but data, and binary form of ASCII string data is the very same ASCII string.

Function names don't have to be visible in `.so`, unless:

- they are global/extern (then they must be visible, so the application loading the shared library can search the functions in memory by their name - during loading of library).
- your `.so` file includes some debug info, use release mode, and `strip` as needed (I do believe the NDK in release mode strips .so files enough, but I never examined it personally, so maybe they leave some debug info even in release?).

So if you want to use native library for obfuscation:

For functions: use cryptic external function names, or add another layer of local functions called trough external (visible) function names, and make sure all debug info is stripped, so local symbols are not included.

For strings: encrypt the data by some encryption, include the encrypted data in .so file, then decrypt the strings into memory before usage by your decryption routine.

Mind you, anyone disassembling your code manually will be still able to find all that stuff out, if he puts enough effort into it.

Comment: Thanks, you have clarified the situation. I just wanted to be sure that the .so files were natively compiled to prevent them from being disassembled as .dex. For compiling multi platform there need some special device or Android Studio takes care of everything when using the NDK?

Comment: @Daniele NDK contains all supported-platforms cross-compilers, you can build all `.so` versions under your host platform (desktop). `.so` files can be disassembled too, but it's disassembling native machine code into ASM/C source. If the machine code is optimized (-O2 or -O3), it's much more difficult to reverse it into easy-to-read source. Disassembling dex/class produces lot more readable results, as those contain binary java opcodes, which quite often "hints" to disassembler what was the source instruction generating them (as Java is simpler language than C/C++ without complex features).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ped7g, you have clarified so well the point now is to learn how to manage all this information. I do not think Android Studio helps a lot in this case, good documentation and examples to follow in my case?

Comment: @Daniele: I'm not sure... I'm avoiding whole time anything practical, because your intent is generic as well, not giving away practical details. What are those secret strings, why do you want to hide them, etc... those subtle context details can change the architecture of chosen obfuscation. So basically read anything on obfuscation and cryptography and see what fits your usage and goals.

Comment: @Daniele also if the `minifyEnabled false` was your setting to see if proguard is clouding your strings, then surprise surprise, it didn't. Did you try to switch it on? Maybe it will obfuscate also the parts you want to hide?

Comment: [@Ped7g] Proguard side java does not obscure strings, are always clear. After reading various articles it seems there are only two methods to obfuscate the strings, one is the native code method using encryption, the other using the Android licensing system. Now the first experiment. Maybe you should write its own encryption method so as not to run into a lack of compatibility.

Comment: @Daniele: you can also encrypt strings in Java, no need to do it in native (except native is a bit more difficult to disassembly, but java+proguard is only 1-2 levels easier, and much simpler to maintain + create = cheaper).